# How can you make WebGL text geometry selectable after you add it to the scene of the viewer?

Tags: javascript, three.js, autodesk-forge

After adding a text geometry object to the viewer, I noticed I am not able to select it with the mouse like I can with the rest of the objects in the viewer. How can I make this selectable? I haven't tried anything, as I have not seen any ideas in the docs. I want to be able to listen for the selection event, which I have down, I just don't know how to make this new TextGeometry object selectable. Here is my code, sorry I didn't include it before.

```
    createText (params) {

    const geometry = new TextGeometry(params.text,
      Object.assign({}, {
        font: new Font(FontJson),
        params
      }))

    const material = this.createColorMaterial(
      params.color)

    const text = new THREE.Mesh(
      geometry , material)

    text.position.set(
      params.position.x,
      params.position.y,
      params.position.z)

    this.viewer.impl.scene.add(text)

    this.viewer.impl.sceneUpdated(true)
  }
```

Thank you!

Comment: we can't really help you without seeing any code. But you would probably make the textgeometry selectable the same way you make any geometry selectable.

Comment: I added my code, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, Forge Viewer will only interact with translated models (SVF, F2D) from Forge Model Derivative service, as well as the Built-in APIs. The text geometry seems like a custom one which is created via `THREE.TextGeometry`, isn't it? You didn't tell much about that.

If you want to interact with custom geometries in Forge Viewer, you must have to implement a `Viewer Tool` and add some self-logic in, such as highlight a text geometry while mouse clicking. You can refer here for the more details: https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/03/creating-tools-for-the-view-data-api.html

Since I didn't see any codes from you here, I assume your text is put into `_viewer.sceneAfter` and here is an example for mouse left clicking:

```
// change color of custom geometries while mouse clicking
handleSingleClick( event, button ) {
  const _viewer = this.viewer;
  const intersectObjects = (function () {
    const pointerVector = new THREE.Vector3();
    const pointerDir = new THREE.Vector3();
    const ray = new THREE.Raycaster();
    const camera = _viewer.impl.camera;

    return function(pointer, objects, recursive) {
        const rect = _viewer.impl.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        const x = (( pointer.clientX - rect.left) / rect.width ) * 2 - 1;
        const y = - (( pointer.clientY - rect.top) / rect.height ) * 2 + 1;

        if (camera.isPerspective) {
            pointerVector.set( x, y, 0.5 );
            pointerVector.unproject( camera );
            ray.set( camera.position, pointerVector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );
        } else {
            pointerVector.set( x, y, -1 );
            pointerVector.unproject( camera );
            pointerDir.set( 0, 0, -1 );
            ray.set( pointerVector, pointerDir.transformDirection( camera.matrixWorld ) );
        }

        const intersections = ray.intersectObjects( objects, recursive );
        return intersections[0] ? intersections[0] : null;
    };
  })();

  const pointer = event.pointers ? event.pointers[ 0 ] : event;
  // Get interseted custom geometries
  const result = intersectObjects( pointer, _viewer.sceneAfter.children );

  if( result && result.object ) {
    const mesh = result.object;
    // Change object color
    let curColor = mesh.material.color;
    curColor = ( curColor.getHex() == 0xff0000 ? 0x00ff00 : 0xff0000 );
    mesh.material.color.setHex( curColor );

    // Rerender
    this.viewer.impl.invalidate( true, true, false );
  }

  return false;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article dedicated to that topic: [Handling custom meshes selection along model components in the Forge Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/handling-custom-meshes-selection-along-model-components-forge-viewer)

Comment: Your post doesn't seem to be working for me. For some reason it picks up the cubes, but not the TextGeometry I have created.